# How to make whole div disappear on deleting content?

Tags: html, css

I am using this class inside a div :

```
.successful {
width: 100%;
background-color: #c2f5b2;
border: solid 1px #89bc79;
color: #29ac00;
padding: .5% 1%;
margin: 1% 0;
display: block;}
```

the div goes like

```
<div class="successful"></div>
```

when i remove the content, the div still shows a green patch. i want the whole div to disappear. i used `display=table` inside the class successfully. it goes fine for forefox, not for chrome. pls help.

Comment: We really need some more information than that. What is the content or what's the wrapper. Provide a jsfiddle at jsfiddle.net for instance.

Answer (score 4):

Try [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aempty) selector:

```
.successful:empty{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Short notice: It's [unsupported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty#Browser_compatibility) in IEs lower than 9.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
style='display:none;'
```

after deleting.

Answer (score 2):

use jquery on deletion activity and hide or display none that dive.

```
style='display:none;'
```

or use like

```
$('any activity at which you want to delete the div').click(function() {

$('.successful').css('display','none');
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You either need to use `javascript` or `jQuery` to solve this.

Here is an example using jQuery.

```
$('.successful').on('keydown', function() {
 if($(this).text().length == 0) {
   $(this).hide();
   }  
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery

```
$(".successful").css("display","none");
```

Though it would be better if you used "#id" for the div instead of ".class"

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in many ways. I just mentioned two in the following link: [jsfiddle - full code](http://jsfiddle.net/PLQ5Y/)!

```
<div class="successful">TEST</div>
```